# Error installing Spring IDE 3.4.0 plugin with Eclipse Kepler: Will not be installed (Spring IDE Roo Support)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, spring-roo, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to install the plugin for Spring IDE (3.4.0) using Eclipse Marketplace for Eclipse Kepler (4.3). It is giving the error 'Will not be installed (Spring IDE Roo Support)'.

I also checked the compatibility of Spring IDE version 3.4.0 with Eclipse Kepler 4.3, and it is compatible. Any ideas on how to complete the installation?

Thank you
Prachi

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some errors on versions 3.4.0 and 4.3.0 (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-kepler-43).

Yoy could try latest releases from http://spring.io/tools/eclipse, or install STS http://spring.io/tools/sts (imho STS is the best option).

Comment: I was able to install 'Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse Kepler (4.3) 3.4.0.RELEASE' from eclipse marketplace for 'Eclipse IDE for JAVA EE developers - Kepler 4.3.0'. Hopefully this should work otherwise I will install STS as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seemed to get hung in the provisioning step (83%). I installed the STS and same problem... but I waited a little longer this time and it was successful. This gave me everything I was expecting in the IDE plugin

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying from https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation using Neon 2.  I have had to stop and start it over and over.